# When do we put quotes in R expressions and when not?

Tags: r

I was learning from swirl about t-tests and this came up:

```
t.test(allMPG, mu = 12.0, alternative = "two.sided")
```

Why do we put quotes on "two.sided" and not on 12.0?

Is there a general rule on how to understand when to use quotes and when not?

Comment: [R language manual](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html) is great resource on data types and their handling in R environment.

Comment: The quick answer is that the interpreter will not try to find a value of either a number or a quoted character value. R names cannot start with digits or operators, so the number 12.0 is unambiguous, but if an unquoted instance of `two.sided` were encountered by R, then R would have gone looking for  a value of that name in its symbol table.

Answer (score 6):

R, like most programming languages, has different "types" of things. And mostly they don't mix. You can't do `12 + "12"` in R. Some languages do let you do that, by converting `"12"` to a number value.

In your example you have numbers and characters. `12.0` is a number value. Its value is 12.0. `"two.sided"` is a character value. Its value is the string of letters and a dot that make it up.

If you use characters and dots and so forth *without* quotes then R thinks this is the *name* of a thing, and tries to replace it with the value of the name of the thing. So:

```
> x = 1  # sets a numeric value
> print(x)  # prints the value of the thing named `x`, which is 1
> print("x") # print the value of the string "x", which is the text character "x".
```

So if you need to use a character (text) value, you use quotes.

Comment: The "And mostly they don't mix. You can't do..." part might lead the OP to think they can safely expect R to always error out when types are accidentally mixed (while silent coercion is common).

Comment: Yet you can do `12 < "12"` and it will give you the correct result.

Comment: And this is "correct"? `12 <"2"`   TRUE? Your response will depend on your understanding of R type coercion.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR:  If you had not put quotes on `two.sided`, the interpreter would have gone out and tried to find a data object whose name was 'two.sided' and most likely would have failed in the attempt. Unquoted text items are considered R symbols with a value to be found in a table of data objects. (Exceptions used to be infrequent, but now abound in the tidyverse world.) Numbers are never quoted.

Rules: (these are my understandings and the real authority would be the R Language (draft) definition: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html ):

-Sequence of digits and symbols ("+", "-", ".", "L", "e") intended to be interpreted as numeric are never quoted. They are considered numeric "literals".

-Another general rule is that sequences of letters and a few symbols (".", "_") that are intended to be looked up for their values should not be quoted. They will be "R names" or "symbols". They will be instances of language objects.

-If you need to have an operator or a space (see the `?Ops` page) inside a character literal then quotes are definitely needed, but advised against.

-Unquoted spaces, commas, linefeeds, and operators are handled specifically by the parser to create a parse-tree. Encountering a `"` (double-quote) or `'` (single-quote) turns off the parsing until the next matching quote.

The most common difficulty that people seem to have is understanding that column names are not first-class objects in R dataframes. They need to be quoted when using in the "["- or "[["-operations when used as literals (versus an intent to look up a character value). The existence of the convenience function "$" for access and assignment to columns has the unfortunate user side-effect of obscuring this distinction. It's use in programming is problematic. The other instance of unquoted reference to columns is seen in the formula interface to regression functions such as `lm` or `glm`, but in those instances people should realize that the formula operator "~" is actually a function that will attempt interpretation of R-names as column references.

There have been elaborations in the last 10 years to the language in both the `data.table`-package and a series of Hadley Wickham-authored packages (plyr, reshape2, gglpot2, dplyr, and more) that have constructed functions that support a "non-standard evaluation" strategy of reference to columns. They are quite popular (for different reasons), but should be understood as relaxing parsing and evaluation rules that are generally imposed by "standard R".

I went for several years before I realized these same rules were being used in the `plotmath` syntax that is supported by base-graphics for plot labeling.

Comment: There are also some base functions with NSE (`subset`, maybe others?).

Comment: @42- do you think this is possibly a bit technical for a clear beginner with no understanding of character and numeric types?

Comment: @Spacedman: I was trying for a "low level" in the sense of a very specific set of rules. The OP asked for "rules" and I thought explaining the parsing rules was what was requested. But this is SO and maybe a less rigorous explanation is desired. This isn't how I would have started explaining R. I would have started with vectors, lists and modes.

Comment: Re what Rich said, your use of a quote block is confusing, since I expect a source for the quote... but it seems you wrote it yourself. Maybe markup like **Rules:** ... **Comments:** without the quote block would be clearer.

Comment: OK. I "made it all up". Wasn't aware that that was a "quote-block". Thought the `>`-operator delivered  an "emphasized non-code block".

Comment: @Frank transform and model.frame come to mind, the latter in how it handles the weights and offset arguments. This also makes it really annoying to handle programatically.